# If quadratic variation of a local martingale is zero then it is itself zero

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, quadratic-variation

Let $M$ be a local martingale, if we need it, we can assume that $M$ is continuous. We know that $\langle M\rangle =0$. This implies that $M$ and $M^2$ are local martingale. Can we conclude that $M=0$? If so, how?

Comment: Can you do it for a martingale?

Comment: @Did Suppose $M$ and $M^2$ is a martingale. We have $M^2\ge 0$. I know that $M^2$ is generally a submartingale if $M$ is a martingale. But how can I use that expectation is constant? If I know that $M_0=0$ than I can prove it. But is it still true without this assumption?

Comment: To ask that M^2 is a martingale is to ask for equality in a conditional Jensen inequality. Does this ring a bell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**: Suppose $M$ is a martingale such that $\langle M \rangle = 0$. Then $M^2$ is a martingale, thus

$$\mathbb{E}(M_t^2-M_0^2) = 0$$

Now use that $$\mathbb{E}(M_t^2 - M_s^2) = \mathbb{E}((M_t-M_s)^2)$$ for all $s \leq t$.