# Continuous local martingale of finite variation is constant

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Is a continuous local martingale $M$ of finite variation constant?

We know that there exists a sequence of stopping times $T_n\nearrow \infty$ a.s. as $n\to\infty$ such that the stopped process $M^{T_n}$ is a continuous bounded martingale. And $M^{T_n}$ has finite variation, because $M$ has finite variation.

Since if $X$ is a continuous bounded martingale with finite variation, then $X=X_0$ a.s. So $M_t^{T_n}=M_0^{T_n}$ a.s. $\forall t\ge 0$ and by letting $n\to\infty$ we obtain that $M\equiv M_0$.

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. The statement "continuous bounded martingale with finite variation implies constant" is a lemma from my notes, but we did not prove it. How would one prove it?

Comment: For 2: If a martingale is continuous and bounded, then it's also a continuous local martingale, no?

Comment: One way is to show, that finite variation implies quadratic variation equals zero and then use this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/473786/445105

Answer (score 6):

Your intuition is good, but there are some technicalities you should be careful about. WLOG $M_0 = 0$. Start by assuming $M$ is a continuous martingale of bounded variation. Then if $B$ is a bound on the variation of $M$, and $(t_i)$ is a partition of $[0,t]$,

$$
E[M_t^2] = E\sum (M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})^2 \leq B E[\sup_i|M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i}|].
$$

Since $M$ is continuous the supremeum tends to $0$ as the partition size goes to $0$. Moreover, the supremum is dominated by $B$, and hence dominated convergence tells us that $E[M_t^2] = 0$, in particular $M_t=0$ a.s. Let $t$ run over rationals and use the continuity of $M$ to conclude that $M=0$.

Next, if $M$ is a continuous local martingale, take a localizing sequence of stopping times $(\tau_n)$. We then find that $M^{\tau_n}_t = 0$ for all $n$, and so taking the limit in $n$ gives $M_t = 0$ a.s. Again let $t$ range over rationals.

Comment: Hi I don't really understand how you came up with the equation for the variance. Would you please explain how you came up with the equality and how you simplified the quadratic variation into the bound and the supremum. Thanks

Comment: @Serena, check that $M$ having bounded variation implies $M_t \in L^2$. For a martingale with each $M_t \in L^2$ one has $ E[M_t^2] = E[(\sum M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_{i}})^2]$. Expand and check that the martingale property implies that all cross terms have expectation zero. The $B$ bound is from $\sum |M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i}| \leq B$ by definition of $B$ being a bound on the variation of $M$. The sup bound is saying any individual $|M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i}|$ is at most the sup over all such terms.

Comment: I thought $M$ having bounded variation meant that  $ M_t  \in L^{1}$

Comment: No, the variation of a function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is defined to be the supremum over all finite partitions of $[a,b]$ of $\sum |f(t_{i+1}) - f({t_i})|$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation

Comment: The variation of a random process $f_\omega(t)$ is the expectation of the the variation of $f:t\to \mathbf{R}$? or just  the variation is almost surely finite?

Comment: How do you get bounded variation and thus the bound B if you only have finite variation?

Comment: @nullUser, why do we let $t$ run on the rationals and not on the reals in the first part?

Comment: @roi_saumon We have $E[M_t^2] =0$ which implies $M_t = 0$ a.s. But the measure zero set on which $M_t = 0$ depends on $t$. Since the rationals are countable, we still have $M_q = 0$ for all rational $q$, a.s., whereas we could not say this if we let $t$ vary over the reals. Since the rationals are dense in the reals, the continuity of $M$ then allows us to conclude $M=0$ a.s. Any countable dense set would have worked, not just $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @nullUser, Thank you. I am still having trouble convincing myself about another detail. How to show properly that $M_t^{\tau_n}=0\;\forall n$ and $\mathbb{P}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\tau_n=\infty)=1$ implies $M_t=0$?

Comment: @roi_saumon On the event that $\tau_n \to \infty$, one has that $\min(\tau_n, t) \to t$ and hence $M_t = \lim_n M_t^{\tau_n} = \lim_n 0 = 0$, so $M_t = 0$ a.s.

Comment: As you are taking the expectation, B depends of the realizations of the process, right? Why did you take it out of the integral ? or better how did you obtain a uniform bound for each realization?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is that simple. I detest posting a link only answer but I feel I am not adding any value by posting anything in addition to this excellent link.

see theorem 3 and lemma 4 of

http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/continuous-local-martingales/