# How should $\int_0^1 |dX_s|$ be understood for a real valued semimartingale $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of finite variation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stieltjes-integral

> How should $\int_0^1 |dX_s|$ be understood for a real valued semimartingale $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of finite variation?

I read this in many sources but I can not find any explanation of this term. I know the stochastic integral but it confuses me that we take the absolute value of $dX_s$.

This notation appears in Theorem 2.3 in this paper: Jacod, J. and Protter, P. (1998). [Asymptotic error distributions for the Euler method for stochastic differential equations](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-26/issue-1/Asymptotic-error-distributions-for-the-Euler-method-for-stochastic-differential/10.1214/aop/1022855419.full). Ann. Probab. 26 267–307. MR1617049

Comment: Could you point to a source that uses it?  It looks like an integral with respect to the total variation, except that semimartingales often have infinite total variation.

Comment: Never seen that before. Sure you didn't mean rather $\int d[X]_{s}$ ?

Comment: Yes, i am sure.

Comment: @ user6247850 I overlooked that $X$ is assumed to have finite variation, sorry for that. It's used in Theorem 2.3 and in the definition before in this paper: JACOD, J. and PROTTER, P. (1998). Asymptotic error distributions for the Euler method for
stochastic differential equations. Ann. Probab. 26 267–307. MR1617049

Comment: If $X$ has finite variation, the integral is then the usual Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral relative to the function $s \mapsto X_s.$ The absolute value means that they are considering absolute value of the jumps.

Comment: @ Will M Can you explain "they are considering absolute value of the jumps."? What does that mean for the integral? Is it not an integral w.r.t. to the variation process?

Comment: It is an $\omega$-by-$\omega$ integral and they are doing what the answer below says. You can check, say, Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas and Shreve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $X_t$ is a continuous semi-martingale; then $X_t$ has the decomposition $$X_t = X_0 + M_t + A_t$$ where $M_t$ is a local martingale and $A_t$ is a process of bounded variation. If $X_t$ has finite variation then $M_t = 0$ (cf. [Continuous local martingale of finite variation is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638447/continuous-local-martingale-of-finite-variation-is-constant)). Thus, we may interpret this integral pathwise; that is, for each $\omega \in \Omega$ $$\int_0^1 |dX_s|(\omega) = \int_0^1 |dA_s|(\omega) = TV(A)(\omega)$$ where $|dA_s|$ is the total variation measure associated with $A_t$ and $TV(A)(\omega)$ is the total variation of $A_t(\omega)$.

Comment: Thanks. Why can you WLOG assume that $X$ is continuous?

Comment: @Learner If $X_t$ is not continuous then the total variation measure can be decomposed into a discrete and continuous part. The integral against the discrete part is just a sum.